# Syntax error resulting from builtin functions in Python33.exe

Tags: python-3.x, syntax-error

I'm quite new to python and I just installed python 3.3.2 in my Win 8 64bit PC.

I tried typing in several builtin functions and I get a syntax error for all of them

For example:-

```
>>>print len("parrot")
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print len("parrot")
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I uninstalled/reinstalled python several times and added the path variable automatically during installation as well as manually after installation.

I suspect this might be something related to Win 8 but I'm not sure. Does anyone else have this issue with Python33 on Win8?

Solutions to get python going would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

print is now a function

```
print(len("parrot"))
```

should work